# Javascript to move images

Tags: javascript, slider, range

I have a script that uses a slider to move an image on its x axis. What I would like to do is use multiple sliders to affect the same image. I have tried duplicating and renaming the move function and slider and it doesn't work:

```
function move(){
    var x = document.getElementById("spin").value;
    var image = document.getElementById("test").style;
    image.marginLeft=x+"px";
}

<input type="range" name="spin" id="spin" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="500"  oninput="move()" style="width:100;"/>
       <div id="test"><h3>Image</h3></div>
```

Thoughts? I have also considered dropping the sliders and using input text fields to control the x axis of the image.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: you want to move one image using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You never specify what didn't worked, but what you provided seams to be fine, you just need to rename it to prevent variable collision between your two function. ( id, variable names, etc )

```js
function movex1(){
    var x = document.getElementById("spinx").value;
    var image = document.getElementById("test").style;
    image.marginLeft=x+"px";
}

function movex2(){
    var x = document.getElementById("spiny").value;
    var image = document.getElementById("test").style;
    let currentMargin = parseInt(image.marginLeft.replace('px', ''));
    image.marginLeft= (currentMargin + parseInt(x)) + "px";
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="spinx" id="spinx" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="500"  oninput="movex1()" style="width:100;"/>
<input type="range" name="spiny" id="spiny" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="500"  oninput="movex2()" style="width:100;"/>

<div id="test"><h3>Image</h3></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your code works perfectly for different axes (x,y). What I need is for both sliders to work on the same axis. Ideally the image would be controlled along the x axis by multiple sliders.

Comment: the same principle applies, you just need to change the moving logic. @user12531517. We don't have any information on what the second slider is suppose to represent so it's hard to produce an accurate results.

Comment: I changed the logic but every time I click and drag the additional slider the image position resets. Each slider is meant to increment/decrement an image along a horizontal timeline...

Comment: make sure all of your slider ids are uniques. @user12531517

Comment: Also, from what i understand, you are never incrementing your left margin, only setting it, so if the first slider goes to 40, it will be set to 40px. but if the second goes to 20, it will be set to 20, not 60.

Comment: That is correct. I need the range sliders to affect the image independently. If the first one slides the image to 40 and the user adds 20 with the second slider, the image will move to 60.

Comment: Thank you! Your programming acumen is very appreciated.